# How can I display the the contents of the bootstrap typeahead suggestions even after a child in the dropdown menu is selected?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap.js. using typeahead I am able to select multiple options with comma separated values. jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/3/

But I want to display the conttents of the dropdown even after a child in the dropdown menu is selected like below image.

[image]

Is it possible to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

It works for multiple select, and you can use the 'closeOnSelect' option to keep the dropdown open as the user selects.

```
 $("#mySel").select2({
        closeOnSelect:false
 });
```

Try the "multiple select" demo here: **http://www.bootply.com/63744**

Comment: Can we add select2 to an input type "text" box. I have jason data like [{"name":"kdjfklsdj", "email":"kjklj@okjfk.com"},{"name":"ksja","email":"kjfk@kjf.com"}]. How can I tell select2 to use the name to search for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) with [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/)

Bootstrap Tags Input has a typeahead option which allows you to set the source:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  }
});
```

or

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {                  
    source: function(query) {
      return $.get('http://someservice.com');
    }
  }
});
```

See also: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/40

Answer (score -1):

You can manually call the `'show'` parameter of your .typeahead instance, like this:

```
$('input:text#YourInputID').typeahead('show');
```

And you can hide it with:

```
$('input:text#YourInputID').typeahead('hide');
```